# .net Publish a web site from Visual Studio and IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to publish a web site with direct function on visual studio.
What I have try: 
I have already try to set debug off for show the error but it return me anyway a generic error.
What can I do for troubleshooting this situation? How can I solve my problem?

Have I to configure the IIS? How?

Comment: What error does it show you? At which point in the publishing process? What have you tried so far?

Comment: and how are you trying to publish it